# Recording calls reliably using pre-installed hidden functionality (Samsung Galaxy)

Tags: samsung, audio, calls, 7.0-nougat, call-recording

While poking around the *activities* available for the pre-installed apps on an older non-rooted Samsung Galaxy Android 7.0 phone, I noticed one for recording phone calls.  It was located in package `com.android.phone`, and the activity is `com.android.phone.RecordCallsAutomaticallyActivity`.

I created a shortcut for the activity and launched it.  Sure enough, it brought up a screen with an option to enable automatically recording phone calls.  I turned on that option and made a call.  I didn't find any new files in `storage/emulated/0`.  I have a hunch it didn't record, but I don't know how to determine that for sure.

Without breaking this question up into a bunch of separate Android SE questions, I'll simply state my objective: **I want to be able to reliably record phone calls.**  Currently, I use an app to do that, but it has failed to record a few recent important calls, and that's a big problem.

So what I'm wondering is:

1. Did I look in the right place to see if the call was recorded?  If not, where do you advise looking?
2. Is there any chance of getting this hidden functionality to work (it is not present in the standard UI) without root?  If so, is there anything else you advise that I try doing?
3. Will rooting the device make any difference?

Comment: Which Android device is it? Is it carrier locked? OEMs may keep some functionality disabled regionwise to comply with local laws. Is call recording (without informing the other party) permitted in your country?

Comment: @Firelord It's a Samsung Galaxy S6.  How do I tell if it's carrier locked?  It was purchased new at retail without a contract or even activating it, if that matters.  I popped in a GSM SIM, and it worked without issue. Call recording is definitely legal here regardless if you tell the other person.  I personally choose to tell the other person because I want them to know there is a record of the call.